# Time series with python

Tags: time-series, python, multivariate-analysis

I've a dataset in following format

```
day,8am,9am,10am,......,8pm
2012-1-1,0.3,0.2,0.21,.....,0.4
2012-1-2,0.32,0.19,0.22,.....,0.45
................
```

I'm not sure whether I processed the whole dataset and get a single time series like follows by combining each day

```
0.3,0.2,0.21,.....,0.4,0.32,0.19,0.22,.....,0.45,........
```

or is there any better way to analyze such a dataset?

I'm not interested in day. I just trying to focus on the values

Comment: This questions is quite unclear in its current form. Can you provide more information? What do 'val1','val2', etc correspond to? Are they the same measurement, just at $N$ different times of the day? Or are they for example readings of different sensors on the same entity?

Comment: @Rickyfox they are hourly measurements of the electricity usage. e.g. 8 am, 9 am, 10 am, etc..

Comment: Then you should replace 'day' with 'hour', resulting in a series of ('hour','measurement') tuples.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get what you mean. Did you mean for exmple use hour as the 1st column and then get all the values of that hour in all the days as the row values?

Comment: that would be convenient for me as I would build a daily total model and then use daily totals to predict hourly usage and then reconcile the daily predictions leading to a forecast for each hour for the next k days. Please post your data as a matrix of 24 columns and k days (rows).

Comment: @IrishStat so are you suggesting to get rid of day column and process the dataset as it is, without any other structural change?

Comment: your format is correct for your purposes. The format I suggested would be more amenable to my approach. Present both here.